# How to Configure a Spring Boot CXF Configuration with more that one service wsdl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wsdl, cxf, config

I have the challenge that I have a WSDL file with more that one service definiton inside

```
----- Customer WSDL file, can not change it ----
  <service name="DocumentOperationService">
    <port name="DocumentOperationPort" binding="tns:DocumentOperationBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL" />
    </port>
  </service>

  <service name="PermissionEvaluatorService">
    <port name="PermissionEvaluatorPort" binding="tns:PermissionEvaluatorBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL" />
    </port>
  </service>

  <service name="ConfigurationResolverService">
    <port name="ConfigurationResolverPort" binding="tns:ConfigurationResolverBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL" />
    </port>
  </service>
------
```

How can I configure the Spring Configuration Class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {
...
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), dmsPortService());

        // CXF JAX-WS implementation relies on the correct ServiceName as QName-Object with
        // the name-Attribute´s text <wsdl:service name="Weather"> and the targetNamespace
        // "http://www.codecentric.de/namespace/weatherservice/"
        // Also the WSDLLocation must be set
        endpoint.setServiceName(dmsOperationService().getServiceName());
        endpoint.setWsdlLocation(dmsOperationService().getWSDLDocumentLocation().toString());
//        endpoint.setWsdlLocation("classpath:/service-api-definition/journalexportservice.wsdl");
        endpoint.publish("/DocumentOperation");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public DocumentOperationService dmsOperationService() {
        // Needed for correct ServiceName & WSDLLocation to publish contract first incl. original WSDL
        return new DocumentOperationService();
    }
```

That all 3 Services are loaded.
In the moment I can only load one Service, I could not find any example how this could be done.
I triad with 3 config files, but then only the last is active, and how to configure 3 services in the same config file I could not figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this [tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/02/spring-boot-apache-cxf/) describing your exact use case with exactly your stack.

In short:

- Your Configuration Bean needs to provide a `ServletRegistrationBean` with a `cxfServlet`, a `SpringBus` and an Endpoint. (Pretty much like your posted code. Juding from the comments it might even be from this very tutorial)
- Your Endpoint should point to the overall wdsl location
- Then you need to implement a Service that encomapsses all of your intended webservices
- In this service you need one method per webservice